# Liferay 6 Gear Icon To Refresh Won't Go Away

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Does anyone know how to get rid of the gear icon in Liferay 6? It's only showing up in one place on my site and it just says *refresh* when you click on it. I'm used to seeing this on the Admin Console to configure the portlet but I've never seen it on the actual site (when you're not in the Admin Console).

[image]

Comment: When you log in as admin and from the liferay dockbar, if you disable `Edit Controls`, does it go away?

Answer (score 0):

This action is active when in liferay-portlet.xml you set  `<render-weight>` to 0 and `<ajaxable>` true. This is useful when you have ajax content in that portlet.